# VSTO, Outlook.exe.config, and <supportedRuntime>

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I've created a VSTO 2.0 SE add-in for Outlook 2007.  Usually, it installs no problem on end-users' machines, but sometimes they have an outlook.exe.config file next to Outlook.exe which specifies that only .NET 1.0 or 1.1 is allowed to load.  For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v1.0.3705" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v1.1.4322" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

In my test environment, if I add the 2.0 runtime to this list, then my add-in loads.  IE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v1.0.3705" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v1.1.4322" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Is there any issue with adding the last line automatically during installation?  If there happens to be another add-in that is using the 1.1 runtime, will both add-ins be able to run side-by-side?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they can't run side-by-side.  Whatever plug-in loads first will determine what version of the CLR will be loaded.  Probably causing other plug-ins to fail.

This is fixed in .NET 4.0

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Simply deleting outlook.exe.config also seems to let my add-in load - is that a good approach or are there other implications to doing that?

Also, when you say this is fixed in 4.0, does that mean a .NET 2.0 add-in, and a .NET 4.0 add-in can run side-by-side?

Comment: You should probably check if the .NET 1.x plug-ins still work properly.  A .config file like that doesn't happen by accident.  Yes, .NET 4.0 allows side-by-side execution.